# 1D Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I need to test CNN on EEG data, and I have heard that 1D-CNN is useful for real-time application. 
I have 5 test subjects with data from 3 sessions each. Each file contain signal from 56 electrodes/channels (56, 260).

I am struggling to find how to set up the CNN and how to input data should be transformed.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
```

How do I choose the input shape for 1DCNN from (15, 56, 260)?

Comment: What is 260? And how do the 3 sessions participate in the data?

Comment: 260 are samples of the signals. So each channel (in total 56 channels) have 260 samples of the signals. 
The EEG signals are extracted from en experiment. Each subject is executing the experiment 4 times (4 sessions), the first 3 sessions are used to train the NN. The target for each session is the subject number

Comment: What do you call "samples", do they form a sequence in time?

Comment: Yes, the signala are Time sequences

Answer (score 0):

So, for a Keras convolution, you should keep it this way: `(examples, time_steps, features)`.

Where:

- examples (usually called samples, but not to be confused with your sensor samples) -  they are the number of examples you have for your model: 15
- time_steps: the continuous sequential measure of your sensors: 260
- features (also channels): the number of independent/parallel channels: 56

Your data then should be shaped as `(15,260,56)`.

If you already have it organized as `(15,56,260)`, you need to **permute or transpose** it, not reshape. You can try [numpy.swapaxes()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html).

Once your data is organized corretly as `(15, 260, 56)`, you can create your network with `input_shape=(260,56)`, or even `input_shape=(None, 56)` in case you want variable length sequences.

---

This is also the same shape you need if you want to try recurrent networks, or even mix recurrent with conv1d.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! But will then the shape of the training data be (15, 260, 56), or should it be transformed into a 1D array?

Comment: That's the shape.