# 1D Convolutional Neural Network with 2D Array

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am experiencing great confusion when setting up 1 channel ECG data input sizes for a 1D CNN.

For simplicity sake, the data is structured like this:

- I have `500` segments
- Each segment has a corresponding label, one of three classes `1.0, 2.0 or 3.0`
- In each segment, there are `100` raw ECG samples (1 channel) i.e. `[1.53, 1.67, 1.56...]`

I have tried to adapt the input-shape from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206786/1d-convolutional-neural-network:) so that would mean my `(examples, time_steps, features)` would be `(500, 100, 1)` and thus my input shape could be `(100,1)` or even `(None, 1)`. However when I run the following:

```
# shape
# x_train shape: (500, 100)
# y_train shape: (500,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) # Not sure if this line is necssary
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax')) # Converge to 3 outputs
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get the following error when calling `model.fit()` :

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 500, 1), found shape=(None, 100)
```

If I then replace the shape with `(None, 500, 1)` and re-run I get this error on `model.add(Dense(n_features, activation='relu'))`:

```
The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? Is it down to the shape of input? Perhaps I have poorly misinterpreted the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a dimension for the batch, which you don't actually have to specify the size of. So maybe try `input_shape = (None, 100)` or `(None, 100, 1)`

Comment: Thank you very much Sean, this solved the issue. Still rather confused why the shape was not using the segments (`500`) but I won't stress further.